# Convert current local time to any other timezone

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

I want to test some time-zone related code by comparing local time to UTC. However this test relies on local time being different to UTC and I'm in the UK so 6 months of the year, local time is UTC according to DateTime comparison tests (due to summer time).

I could hard-code my test to convert UTCNow to a certain timezone like EST but on the off-chance my code was used in an American system, now I have the same issue.

So is there a way I can easily convert DateTime.UtcNow to a timezone that's definitely different to my local timezone, without hard-coding it or making assumptions what timezone I'm in?

Comment: Not sure that I understand you correctly, but if you want to convert UTC to another zone https://github.com/tym32167/arma3beclient/blob/master/src/Arma3BE.Client.Infrastructure/Extensions/DateTimeExtension.cs

Comment: also, you can get zones which differs from local ```var zone = TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones().Where(x=>x.BaseUtcOffset != TimeZoneInfo.Local.BaseUtcOffset).First();```

Comment: @tym32167 yeah I want to convert UTC to a timezone which is NOT the same as my local timezone, and where the local time is definitely different to UTC. I think your comments are on the right track, can you provide an answer elaborating on this?

Comment: So, my comments above should help you

Comment: Yes but they would help me, and others in the future, more as an answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, as I mentoined in comments, if you want to get timezones which differs from yours, you can do it in that way:

```
var zone = TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones()
           .Where(x=>x.BaseUtcOffset != TimeZoneInfo.Local.BaseUtcOffset)
           .First();
```

To convert UTC DateTime to another timezone, you have to use [TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezoneinfo.converttimefromutc%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), sample:

```
var datetime = // datetime in UTC, for example, DateTime.UtcNow
var zone = // target zone
return TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(datetime, zone);
```

You can check samples in my pet project [here](https://github.com/tym32167/arma3beclient/blob/master/src/Arma3BE.Client.Infrastructure/Extensions/DateTimeExtension.cs)

Comment: It's a nice little solution.

Comment: The problem with this is you lose the zone info on the date, it becomes local, so if you store it or use DateTime arithmetic it fails miserably. It's one of the biggest caveats with .net and internationalization.

Answer (score 1):

Time zones in .net are a very confusing matter. DateTime only supports local and UTC timezones really, it has no concept of different zones as it only gets the current offset from the machine and applies it to a tick count value which is in UTC.

So at a first there's no way to change to another timezone, but you can simulate something. If you want per example simulate a timezone GMT+2, you must first retrieve the current zone offset and add the difference of this offset and the desired offset to the local date, something like this:

```
TimeSpan targetOffset = new TimeSpan(2, 0, 0) - TimeZoneInfo.Local.BaseUtcOffset; //target to GMT+2
DateTime targetNow = DateTime.Now + targetOffset;
```

In this way the Date will have the values like if it were on that timezone, but for calculations using the datetime object and not just the year/month/day/hour/minute/second all of them will be wrong as the object will be marked as local and thus will have the wrong values.

To solve this you have two options, reverse your logic (convert non-local time to local time) or just work with UTC dates.

The first approach is very easy:

```
DateTime nonLocal = new DateTime(2016, 10, 21, 13, 33, 0); //We suppose we want 2016-10-21 13:33:00 at GMT+2
DateTime local = nonLocal + (TimeZoneInfo.Local.BaseUtcOffset - new TimeSpan(2, 0, 0));
```

This will yield to correct DateTime operations, but, here we go again with problems, if you use the year/month/day/hour/minute they will be in your local zone, not in the supposed zone and code using these properties will fail.

Finally, the best approach is the second one, you just forget about timezones and whenever you get a DateTime you convert it to UTC, all will work flawlesly and when you need to represent the data just convert it to local and all is done, no need to worry about DateTime arithmetic or properties differing just because they're on another timezone.

Answer (score -1):

```
 public static class DateTimeExtensions
    {
        public static DateTime As(this DateTime source, string timeZoneName)
        {
            DateTime utcTime = DateTime.SpecifyKind(source, DateTimeKind.Unspecified);
            TimeZoneInfo newTimeZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(timeZoneName);
            return TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(utcTime, newTimeZone);
        }
    }
```

Usage:

```
        DateTime date1 = DateTime.UtcNow;
        DateTime date2 = date1.As("Eastern Standard Time");
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question... it forces me to specify the timezone rather than automatically pick one.

Comment: This covers the "easily convert DateTime.UtcNow to a timezone that's definitely different to my local timezone". Just because the timezone is hardcoded in the example doesn't mean you have to do the same. you can feed a random one. And you have 3 examples on how to do that on this page.